# Ical parsing Propose new time with Outlook

Tags: outlook, icalendar

I'm building a web application that sends meeting requests to user's Outlook. Every meeting request is created with a virtual organiser. Then, I have a service that is polling the virtual organiser's pop3 inbox to retreive attendees response to the meeting request (Accept/Decline/Propose new time).

All the information is parsed using the ICal string that outlook sends. Now I'm able to detect if an attendee has accepted or declined easily. I can also detect if the attendee proposed a new time but my problem is that there is no where in the ICal string I can fin the actual new time proposed, except in the email message, which is something I really don'T want to parse :)

Anybody knows where I can find the new time proposed without parsing the email message itself?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how Outlook does these things, but the proper way to propose a change to the appointment date is:

- List item
- You send a METHOD:REQUEST, not a METHOD:REPLY.
- You identify the appointment you are referring to via the UID property.
- If you change the DTSTART, you propose to change the start date (DTEND for the end date...).

This is explained in iTIP, RFC 2446, 3.2.2.1, "Rescheduling an event"

So the information you need should be in the ICAL file

Comment: I understand, but the thing is that I think Outlook does not seem to respect the ICAL standard when rescheduling an event. So when I receive an answer from Outlook, there is noway I can find the proposed new time in the ICAL string generated by Outlook.

Comment: I finally found the answer, the problem was not Outlook, it is because of the Exchange version. Exchange 2003 does not relay the proposed new time outside of the domain. Why is that? I really don't know but it's a fact. I tried with Exchange 2007 and it worked fine, the new time proposed was in the ICAL string at the other end.

Comment: @jerrydev Do you still have the format of the ICal string sent by Exchange to propose a new time?